# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component, getting this error while making a function call

Tags: react-native

I have created a custom hook which triggers a API request on click of a button.

my code stricture is like:

parent component:

```
import HookComponent from "./HookComponent";

const parentComponent=()=>{

const callHook=()=>{

const [response,error]=HookComponent()

}

return(
//inside a button component triggering the function  
 onPress={()=>callHook()}

}


Hook:

const HookComponent =()=>{
...
//making API CALL
return [response,error]
}

export default HookComponent;
```

while trying this getting a error  like:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

How can I fix this issue?
TIA,
  Farukh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const callHook=()=>{
   const [response,error] = HookComponent()
}
```

is the illegal operation you try to do, because you calling the hook not at the body of the component, but something you can do is to return from your hook a `refresh` function as well

```
                               // changed it to pattern hook naming
const [response,error, refresh]= useHookComponent()
const callHook= () => refresh()
```

```
const useHookComponent = () => {
  ...
  //making API CALL
  ...
  const refresh = () => //making API CALL AGAIN
  return [response, error, refresh]
}

export default useHookComponent;
```

If you will provide more of your custom hook implemtenion I will be able to update `refresh` and rest usage as well, anyhow hope it's helpful